# UIPageViewController programmatically swift 4

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uipagecontrol

I wrote this code that checked several times I can not understand where I'm wrong. 
I can not see my page..
but I see a black background with the 3 dots of pageControl.

I checked several times, I set the yellow background on the first page..

can you give me a hand?

I have 3-4 more files in which I declare the pages and their layout

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHiFl.jpg)

```
final class IntroViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

    var introRouter: IntroRouter?
    var pages = [UIViewController]()
    let pageControl = UIPageControl()

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent

//        self.delegate = self
        let initialPage = 1
        let page1 = ViewController1()
        let page2 = ViewController2()
        let page3 = ViewController3()
        let page4 = ViewController4()

        self.pages.append(page1)
        self.pages.append(page2)
        self.pages.append(page3)
        self.pages.append(page4)
        setViewControllers([pages[initialPage]], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

        self.pageControl.frame = CGRect()
        self.pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.black
        self.pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.lightGray
        self.pageControl.numberOfPages = self.pages.count
        self.pageControl.currentPage = initialPage
        self.view.addSubview(self.pageControl)

        self.pageControl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.pageControl.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
        self.pageControl.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.widthAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
        self.pageControl.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
        self.pageControl.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupUI()
        arrangeSubviews()
    }

    override init(transitionStyle style: UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle, navigationOrientation: UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientation, options: [String : Any]? = nil) {
        super.init(transitionStyle: style, navigationOrientation: navigationOrientation, options: options)
    }
    func setRouter(introRouter: IntroRouter) {
        self.introRouter = introRouter
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

private extension IntroViewController {

    func IntroViewController(_ IntroViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        if let viewControllerIndex = self.pages.index(of: viewController) {
            if viewControllerIndex == 0 {
                // wrap to last page in array
                return self.pages.last
            } else {
                // go to previous page in array
                return self.pages[viewControllerIndex - 1]
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    func IntroViewController(_ IntroViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        if let viewControllerIndex = self.pages.index(of: viewController) {
            if viewControllerIndex < self.pages.count - 1 {
                // go to next page in array
                return self.pages[viewControllerIndex + 1]
            } else {
                // wrap to first page in array
                return self.pages.first
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    func IntroViewController(_ IntroViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {

        // set the pageControl.currentPage to the index of the current viewController in pages
        if let viewControllers = IntroViewController.viewControllers {
            if let viewControllerIndex = self.pages.index(of: viewControllers[0]) {
                self.pageControl.currentPage = viewControllerIndex
            }
        }
    }

    func setupUI() {

        pageControl.do {
            $0.numberOfPages = 4
            $0.currentPage = 1
            $0.pageIndicatorTintColor = .lightGray
            $0.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = Theme.Colors.white
        }
    }

    func arrangeSubviews() {
        view.addSubview(pageControl)
    }
}
```

Comment: First, there are a number of things wrong with the code you posted - you should take a look at this: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Second, are you sure your "page" view controllers are creating valid views?

Comment: If you're viewControllers are empty you will see a black screen. For test you should give them an arbitrary color background